# NurbsPath causes object to rotate when specified in Curve modifier. Not seeing why

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

I'm following a 2.79 tutorial with a 2.8 release.
At one point the video is trying to curve the blade using a Path and the Curve modifier.

I've tried moving the origin points of the blade object and the path to the same place in 3d space but it's still rotates the 3d object 180 degrees in Object mode.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You rotated the path in object mode!
Apply rotation to your path and blade if needed.
Check the origin, in your case looks fine, path and Blade should be at same location.
Also in your case looks fine, but paths arrows should look in the direction you want to let follow objects.